# Gradle 100% CPU usage results in build cancellation

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

When trying to build a project, which is quite big, CPU usage is usually around 70-80%. 
However when it gets to the point of "compileJava", it goes up to a constant 90-100%, resulting in a spam of the error

```
"Expiring Daemon because JVM Tenured space is exhausted
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build after running out of JVM memory"
```

After a while the build cancels with either

```
"Cause: invalid type code: 02"
```

or

```
"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"
```

The latter does not appear anymore after some of the things I've tried.

I've tried pretty much everything that I could find. Set env. java options to increase available memory, set the gradle.properties to

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=2048m -Xmx2048m
```

I have added the following to the IDEA VM Options with no success

```
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Xmx10g
```

And me as well as the internet is out of ideas.

Comment: Try specifying the options [here instead](https://i.imgur.com/leTra7I.png).

Comment: Didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: Does it build without issues outside of IntelliJ IDEA with the same Gradle/Java versions?

Comment: It actually works in the command line itself. Welp, gonna go back to vs code then.

Comment: Note that editing IDEA VM Options will not have any effect on the Gradle build. Try the following in the `gradle.properties`: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m`

Comment: That's already in there. Compiling from command line seems to work so I'm just gonna do that from now on, thanks.